# Issue Enabling VNC Access on Mojave 10.14

Tags: mojave, remote-desktop

I am aware of the answers posted online for this, mainly that I need to allow permission to `/Library/vnc/vncagent` in the Security & Privacy section of System Preferences.

However I cannot find "vnc" under the Library folder, or any mention at all of "vncagent".

Answer (score 2):

Did you install VNC Server? This will create the vnc directory for you and install the "vncagent" and you will be able to allow/add the vncagent under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility

https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/

[image: vnc agent after vnc server install]